# Get the inserted Project name from a Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I want to create a little MVVM Template for Visual Studio 2019. In general, there are two projects:

`'$Projectname$_Model'` and `'$Projectname$_View_VM'`

Microsoft says, that this parameter is the inserted project name. It even works almost fine, there's only one problem. 
The View Model has a Reference to Model, which needs to get renamed too. So if I create the Project "Testproj", then I need to get:

`'Testproj_Model', 'Testproj_View_VM'` and the Reference to `'Testproj_Model'` in `'Testproj_View_VM'`

But in reality, the Reference is called `"Testproj_View_VM_Model"`. I guess the parameter uses the projectname `"Testproj_View_VM"` so I need another parameter than $Projectname$ that gives me specifically the `"Testproj"`.

I tried it with `$SpecificSolutionName$` but that doesn't work either

This is the part in my csproj that doesn't work:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project_Model\Project_Model.csproj">
  <Project>{E172D850-7FE1-4AE2-B56A-DD038C630DF9}</Project>
  <Name>$ext_safeprojectname$_Model</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Microsoft says that ext_* will work too, but this parameter won't get dissolved at all

Comment: Out of topic but in my experience a template for MVVM is useless unless you're willing to maintain it for newer versions of MVVM or you're going to stick with the same MVVM version. I work in a MVVM project so I know a bit about MVVM history. Their developers change way too much the framework, I tried many templates and they eventually get obsolete.

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco It's just a small internal template for me, and I don't know how to fix the Reference problem

Comment: Hi friend, what project do you creates? VSIX or Item Template Project?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I create a Project Template, idk if it's VSIX then

Comment: Hi friend, could you share a simple sample to help reproduce this issue? And I think something is wrong with your project reference. Usually the `Name` should be corresponding to the Name.csproj in `Include`.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT This is the complete Project Template:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/3j59z2654klbtj1/Project_MVVM.zip/file

Comment: I can't reproduce the same issue here. The example you shared is a project. But in my opinion, it should be a solution with the two both projects. And i think this issue has something related to the $SafeProjectName$, when you use this way in .csproj file, I think it refers to the current project name.